# Как сделать ограничение на ввод?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт, который ограничивает кол-во вводных символов до 3х и разрешены только цифры.

Но баг в том, что после того, как ввел 3 символа, убрал фокус с инпута, а потом еще раз взял в фокус инпут, то 3-й символ удаляется.

Как исправить скрипт так, чтобы можно было вводить ТОЛЬКО цифры, НЕЛЬЗЯ вводить первым 0, ограничить ввод только до 3 символов?

```js
$('body').on('click keypress', '.btn-input', function(key) {
  $this = $(this);
  $maxLen = 2;
  if (key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;
  if ($this.val().length > $maxLen)
    $this.val($this.val().substr(0, $maxLen));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn-input order-count" type="text" >
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/4gym7k8h/](https://jsfiddle.net/4gym7k8h)

Comment: замени `keypress` на `keyup`, а строку `if (key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;`  поставь в самый конец,

Comment: Да, работает. Но мне не нравится то, что символы пропадают на глазах, а хотелось, чтобы они просто не вводились. + Я могу вводить буквы, а до этого буквы не вводились

Comment: ну ладно, тогда после `$maxLen = 2;` оставь вот так только: `if ($this.val().length > $maxLen)
   return false;
    
  if (key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;`  ........... https://jsfiddle.net/4gym7k8h/1/

Comment: Во, так работает. Но как теперь сделать, чтобы 0 первым нельзя было ввести?

Comment: немного логики и `if ($this.val().length == 0 && key.charCode == 48)  
   return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('body').on('click keypress', '.btn-input', function(key) {
  $this = $(this);
  $maxLen = 2;
  // ограничение по длине
  if ($this.val().length > $maxLen)
    return false;
  // ограничение по вводу нуля в начале
  if ($this.val().length == 0 && key.charCode == 48)  
    return false;
  // ограничение по символам
  if (key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) 
    return false;  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn-input order-count" type="text" >
```

Comment: Следует заметить, что данный вариант все равно позволяет вставить в поле (Ctrl-V) произвольный текст произвольной длины. :)

Comment: @Yaant ну тут в зависимости от типа браузера и пожелания трудящихся зависит всё. Например для некоторых браузеров вообще достаточно написать атрибут `maxlength="3"` в инпуте и не париться скриптом и не беспокоится о Ctrl-V ))  так или иначе если поле рассчитано на конкретное количество цифр, то юзеру нет смысла обманывать. А если специально обманывает, то это плохой дядя и от него, так или иначе, проверка на сервере должна быть..... в общем, тут можно много чего и навернуть и пришлёпать...... всё зависит....